# PHP - special regular expression

Tags: php, regex

i have got this string :

```
var wcall=wicketAjaxGet('?x=-DxRtr1ApWy1S-JoAgFwCid5mDvsjhWOhXpq0nZdO*WsUggdTvpUtQ',function() { }.bind(this),function() { }.bind(this), function() {
```

And i need to get this :

```
?x=-DxRtr1ApWy1S-JoAgFwCid5mDvsjhWOhXpq0nZdO*WsUggdTvpUtQ
```

How can i do that in PHP?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this

```
<?php
if (preg_match("/wicketAjaxGet\('([^']*)'/", $your_string, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1]; // here is what you are looking for
}
```